# XSLT String Wrap:How do I wrap words in a String at New line character(\n)

Tags: xml, string, xslt, xslt-2.0

We want to write XSLT transformation for given XML.
We are trying to text wrap for comment element at newline character on pressing of ENTER KEY. In that, `<Comment>` elements Splits across 6 different line items after applying XSLT Transformation.

**Note:** 
Here "\n" is the linefeed character. It means end the present line and go to a new line.

We tried  following :

Pattern observed in it:
`<StockCode>` element is blank for all having comment substring at each line items. while StockCode element is having value for all those `<comment>` element is blank
`<OrderDetail>` is repeating node here.

**Input XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>

-<SalesOrders xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

-<Orders>

-<OrderHeader>

<Customer>000016</Customer>
<OrderDate>2016-04-19</OrderDate>
<SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-411324</SalesForceOrderNumber>
</OrderHeader>
-<OrderDetails>
-<StockLine>
<StockCode>ABB-CDE-FGH-01</StockCode>
<OrderDescription>EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS C3 Generic LOC 0833 Expected arrival 01/07/2016  OTYPE NE TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321</OrderDescription>
</comment>
<OrderLineID>OR-1561179</OrderLineID>
</StockLine>
</OrderDetails>
</Orders>
</SalesOrders>

-<OrderDetails> ---------------------
-<StockLine>
<StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
</Comment>
<OrderLineID>OR-1561180</OrderLineID>
</StockLine>
</OrderDetails>
</Orders>
</SalesOrders>
-<OrderDetails>
-<StockLine>
<StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
</Comment>
<OrderLineID>OR-1561181</OrderLineID>
</StockLine>
</OrderDetails>
</Orders>
</SalesOrders>
-<OrderDetails>
-<StockLine>
<StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
</Comment>
<OrderLineID>OR-1561182</OrderLineID>
</StockLine>
</OrderDetails>
</Orders>
</SalesOrders>
-<OrderDetails>
-<StockLine>
<StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
</Comment>
<OrderLineID>OR-1561183</OrderLineID>
</StockLine>
</OrderDetails>
</Orders>
</SalesOrders>
-<OrderDetails>
-<StockLine>
<StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
</Comment>
<OrderLineID>OR-1561184</OrderLineID>
</StockLine>
</OrderDetails>
</Orders>
</SalesOrders
```

**Expected XML After XSLT transformation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>

-<SalesOrders xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

-<Orders>

-<OrderHeader>

<Customer>000016</Customer>
<OrderDate>2016-04-19</OrderDate>
<SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-411324</SalesForceOrderNumber>
</OrderHeader>
-<OrderDetails>
-<StockLine>
<StockCode>ABB-CDE-FGH-01</StockCode>
<Comment>Nil</Comment>
<OrderLineID>OR-1561179</OrderLineID>
</StockLine>
</OrderDetails>
</Orders>
</SalesOrders>

-<OrderDetails> ---------------------
-<StockLine>
<StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
<Comment>EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS</Comment>
<OrderLineID>OR-1561180</OrderLineID>
</StockLine>
</OrderDetails>
</Orders>
</SalesOrders>
-<OrderDetails>
-<StockLine>
<StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
<Comment>C3 Generic</Comment>
<OrderLineID>OR-1561181</OrderLineID>
</StockLine>
</OrderDetails>
</Orders>
</SalesOrders>
-<OrderDetails>
-<StockLine>
<StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
<Comment>LOC 0833</Comment>
<OrderLineID>OR-1561182</OrderLineID>
</StockLine>
</OrderDetails>
</Orders>
</SalesOrders>
-<OrderDetails>
-<StockLine>
<StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
<Comment>OTYPE NE</Comment>
<OrderLineID>OR-1561183</OrderLineID>
</StockLine>
</OrderDetails>
</Orders>
</SalesOrders>
-<OrderDetails>
-<StockLine>
<StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
<Comment>TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321</Comment>
<OrderLineID>OR-1561184</OrderLineID>
</StockLine>
</OrderDetails>
</Orders>
</SalesOrders
```

The above code splits into 6 diffrent line items(that is  for each OrderLineID) In that,we are trying to Achieve Substring on comment field.

How to Write  XSLT transformation file for Comment Substring at new line character?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: I find your question incomprehensible. I see no newline characters in your input. There is data in your output that is nowhere in your input. And your link demands registration.

Comment: This is my Input XML  for XSLT transformation:http://paste.ofcode.org/ZwmuKhhWP3VvgQXiapQuhH

Comment: <Comment> element consist of string  that  splits at newline character into 6 different Line items that is <OrderLineID>

Comment: Please post you input (and all the required code) in your question, not in comments or external links. See also: [mcve]

Comment: I edited the Question.  Please Look  for <Comment> element it has to split at newline character  ACROSS diffrent line id <OrderLineId> for each <OrderDetail> repeated Node.

Comment: Make sure we understand if the Comment contains the literal string '\n" or an actual carriage return or line feed character.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116258/discussion-between-vickps-and-michael-hor257k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To minimize the problem to the main question here, consider the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OrderDetails">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="stockcode" select="StockLine/StockCode" />
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(StockLine/Comment, '\\n')">
            <StockLine>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$stockcode"/>
                <Comment>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                </Comment>
                <OrderLineID>???</OrderLineID>
            </StockLine>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following input:

**XML**

```
<SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
  <Orders>
    <OrderHeader>
      <Customer>000016</Customer>
      <OrderDate>2016-04-19</OrderDate>
      <SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-411324</SalesForceOrderNumber>
    </OrderHeader>
    <OrderDetails>
      <StockLine>
        <StockCode>NIL</StockCode>
        <Comment>EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS\n C3 Generic\n LOC 0833\n Expected arrival 01/07/2016\n  OTYPE NE\n TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321</Comment>
      </StockLine>
    </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
</SalesOrders>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
   <Orders>
      <OrderHeader>
         <Customer>000016</Customer>
         <OrderDate>2016-04-19</OrderDate>
         <SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-411324</SalesForceOrderNumber>
      </OrderHeader>
      <OrderDetails>
         <StockLine>
            <StockCode>NIL</StockCode>
            <Comment>EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>???</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <StockCode>NIL</StockCode>
            <Comment>C3 Generic</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>???</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <StockCode>NIL</StockCode>
            <Comment>LOC 0833</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>???</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <StockCode>NIL</StockCode>
            <Comment>Expected arrival 01/07/2016</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>???</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <StockCode>NIL</StockCode>
            <Comment>OTYPE NE</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>???</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <StockCode>NIL</StockCode>
            <Comment>TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>???</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
      </OrderDetails>
   </Orders>
</SalesOrders>
```

I have no idea where the contents of `OrderLineID` are supposed to come from.

---

**Important:**

If the input `Comment` contains actual linefeed characters - IOW, if your actual input is:

**XML**

```
<SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
  <Orders>
    <OrderHeader>
      <Customer>000016</Customer>
      <OrderDate>2016-04-19</OrderDate>
      <SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-411324</SalesForceOrderNumber>
    </OrderHeader>
    <OrderDetails>
      <StockLine>
        <StockCode>NIL</StockCode>
        <Comment>EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS
C3 Generic
LOC 0833
Expected arrival 01/07/2016
 OTYPE NE
TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321</Comment>
      </StockLine>
    </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
</SalesOrders>
```

then use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(StockLine/Comment, '\n')">
```

---

### Added:

Given the following input:

**XML**

```
<SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
  <Orders>
    <OrderHeader>
      <Customer>000016</Customer>
      <OrderDate>2016-04-19</OrderDate>
      <SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-411324</SalesForceOrderNumber>
    </OrderHeader>
    <OrderDetails>
      <StockLine>
        <StockCode>ABB-CDE-FGH-01</StockCode>
        <OrderDescription>EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS
C3 Generic
LOC 0833
Expected arrival 01/07/2016
 OTYPE NE
TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321</OrderDescription>
        <OrderLineID>OR-1561179</OrderLineID>
      </StockLine>
      <StockLine>
        <StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
        <OrderLineID>OR-1561180</OrderLineID>
      </StockLine>
      <StockLine>
        <StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
        <OrderLineID>OR-1561181</OrderLineID>
      </StockLine>
      <StockLine>
        <StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
        <OrderLineID>OR-1561182</OrderLineID>
      </StockLine>
      <StockLine>
        <StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
        <OrderLineID>OR-1561183</OrderLineID>
      </StockLine>
      <StockLine>
        <StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
        <OrderLineID>OR-1561184</OrderLineID>
      </StockLine>
    </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
</SalesOrders>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="StockLine">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="StockCode"/>
        <Comment>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(tokenize(../StockLine[1]/OrderDescription, '\n')[$i])"/>
        </Comment>
        <xsl:copy-of select="OrderLineID"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
   <Orders>
      <OrderHeader>
         <Customer>000016</Customer>
         <OrderDate>2016-04-19</OrderDate>
         <SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-411324</SalesForceOrderNumber>
      </OrderHeader>
      <OrderDetails>
         <StockLine>
            <StockCode>ABB-CDE-FGH-01</StockCode>
            <Comment>EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1561179</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
            <Comment>C3 Generic</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1561180</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
            <Comment>LOC 0833</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1561181</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
            <Comment>Expected arrival 01/07/2016</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1561182</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
            <Comment>OTYPE NE</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1561183</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <StockCode>Nil</StockCode>
            <Comment>TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1561184</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
      </OrderDetails>
   </Orders>
</SalesOrders>
```

Comment: First off, Thanks for supporting me and giving me nice solution.  You were correct i  have  given wrong information about Input. i am going to correct  on this  <OrderLineID>

Comment: Definatly i will put this as answer . Also Wanted to  make sure <OrderLineID> Is unique element for all comment.   it is basically Line Items in sales Order Data. For more clear picture i   wanted to produce How these Enteries is looking at database. Please consider this link :http://paste.ofcode.org/KbgzFqYqUUaSGpTQFgarWh

Comment: This Link consist of  Actual result after processing XSLT  ON  XML. So each  NComment Field  is comment here against <orderLineID> unique number that is CORRESPONDS TO SalesOrderline items in database. Also for StockCode value we do not have comment .

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what all that means. -- Note that the new input you have posted is not well-formed XML and cannot be processed at all.

Comment: I formatted my Input XML .Going to choose this as answer. and i will get back to you after applying into actual condition of my  system. Thanks a ton .

Comment: "*I formatted my Input XML.*" It's still a mess. FWIW, I have added what I *think* relates to your question in its new form. You will have to adapt this to your actual structure (which I wasn't able to detect from your post).

Comment: You sorted out better way . Added section looks more relevant to me. Thanks again.

Comment: XSLT is working for me. Only i have to take care  WHEN <StockCode > value is  empty  then <Comment> element  should have  these  splitted values.  Do i capture  this logic in XSLT itself. that always look for empty StockCode values and then Put those comment in  sequential order. In that way comment always goes to correct <OrderLineID>.  Thanks for supporting me throughout and  giving me  nice solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116280/discussion-between-vickps-and-michael-hor257k).

Comment: @vickps I suggest you post a new question, with an example that shows the added complication. This answer is already long enough.

Comment: Posted New One here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167552/xslt-condition-for-check-if-null-and-empty-element-then-only-assign-value-to-ot