# XSLT :Condition for check if null and empty element then only assign value to other element

Tags: xml, string, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

We have input XML.In that,StockCode element is empty for many line items (OrderLineID elements). For all empty StockCode element in XML there must be Comment element value. Similarly,For all such empty  Comment elements  there must be  StockCode Value Exist.

**Note** :
**OrderDetail** is repeating Node here.

**Scenario**:

We have to split OrderDescription string . such a way  that it always look for empty StockCode element. then only Assign split string values to Comment elements. Otherwise for all StockCode having value should not assign split string to Comment Element

**INPUT XML :**

```
<SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
      <Orders>
        <OrderHeader>
          <Customer>000016</Customer>
          <OrderDate>2016-04-19</OrderDate>
          <SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-411324</SalesForceOrderNumber>
        </OrderHeader>
        <OrderDetails>
          <StockLine>
            <StockCode>ABB-CDE-FGH-01</StockCode>
            <OrderDescription>EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS
    C3 Generic
    LOC 0833
    Expected arrival 01/07/2016
     OTYPE NE
    TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321</OrderDescription>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1561179</OrderLineID>
          </StockLine>
           <StockLine>
                    <StockCode>BCD-EFGH-01</StockCode>
                    <OrderLineID>OR-1561186</OrderLineID>
                    </Comment>
                  </StockLine>
          <StockLine>
            <StockCode></StockCode>
            </Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1561180</OrderLineID>
          </StockLine>
          <StockLine>
            <StockCode></StockCode>
            </Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1561181</OrderLineID>
          </StockLine>
          <StockLine>
            <StockCode></StockCode>
            </Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1561182</OrderLineID>
          </StockLine>
          <StockLine>
            <StockCode></StockCode>
            </Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1561183</OrderLineID>
          </StockLine>
          <StockLine>
            <StockCode></StockCode>
            </Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1561184</OrderLineID>
          </StockLine>
           <StockLine>
            <StockCode></StockCode>
            </Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1561185</OrderLineID>
          </StockLine>
        </OrderDetails>
      </Orders>
    </SalesOrders>
```

**Existing XSLT For Transformation:**

**XSLT2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="StockLine">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="StockCode"/>
            <Comment>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(tokenize(../StockLine[1]/OrderDescription, '\n')[$i])"/>
            </Comment>
            <xsl:copy-of select="OrderLineID"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output value:

```
<SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
              <Orders>
                <OrderHeader>
                  <Customer>000016</Customer>
                  <OrderDate>2016-04-19</OrderDate>
                  <SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-411324</SalesForceOrderNumber>
                </OrderHeader>
                <OrderDetails>
                  <StockLine>
                    <StockCode>ABB-CDE-FGH-01</StockCode>
                    </Comment>
                    <OrderDescription>EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS
            C3 Generic
            LOC 0833
            Expected arrival 01/07/2016
             OTYPE NE
            TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321</OrderDescription>
                    <OrderLineID>OR-1561179</OrderLineID>
                  </StockLine>
                   <StockLine>
                    <StockCode>BCD-EFGH-01</StockCode>
                    <OrderLineID>OR-1561186</OrderLineID>
                    </Comment>
                  </StockLine>
                  <StockLine>
                    <Comment>EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS</Comment>
                    </StockCode>
                    <OrderLineID>OR-1561180</OrderLineID>
                  </StockLine>
                  <StockLine>
                    <Comment>C3 Generic</Comment>
                    </StockCode>
                    <OrderLineID>OR-1561181</OrderLineID>
                  </StockLine>
                  <StockLine>
                    <Comment>LOC 0833</Comment>
                    </StockCode>
                    <OrderLineID>OR-1561182</OrderLineID>
                  </StockLine>
                  <StockLine>
                    <Comment>Expected arrival 01/07/2016</Comment>
                    </StockCode>
                    <OrderLineID>OR-1561183</OrderLineID>
                  </StockLine>
                  <StockLine>
                    <Comment> OTYPE NE</Comment>
                    </StockCode>
                    <OrderLineID>OR-1561184</OrderLineID>
                  </StockLine>
                  <StockLine>
                    <Comment>TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321</Comment>
                    </StockCode>
                    <OrderLineID>OR-1561185</OrderLineID>
                  </StockLine>
                </OrderDetails>
              </Orders>
            </SalesOrders>
```

Comment: Let me know if it is  readable.<>  it is making invisible word in my question body. please remove down vote or suggest if any more changes required!

Comment: please remove down vote  from question else suggest changes in it.

Comment: What do you consider "StockCode element is empty"? Is `<StockCode>Nil</StockCode>` an empty element?

Comment: Thanks for catch  i just corrected the question <StockCode>Nil</StockCode> replaced with <StockCode></StockCode>.

Comment: Your input has 5 StockLine with Nill StockCode - You output has 7 StockLines - one for each line of description plus another that's appear out of nowhere.  The Comment (or is it comment) node appears at random.   This question is an extension of a similar question answered yesterday by michael.hor257k. but Michaels anwser has better quality xml!  Can you please give clearer examples of your input and output xml.

Comment: i checked the question after Your Comment. Now input is 7 with expected output. and please consider <Comment> everywhere instead of <comment> . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion tokenizing once and passing on the value as a parameter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OrderDetails">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="descriptions" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(StockLine[1]/OrderDescription, '\n')"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:with-param name="descriptions" as="xs:string*" select="$descriptions" tunnel="yes"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="StockLine/StockCode[not(normalize-space())]">
        <xsl:param name="descriptions" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer">
            <xsl:number count="StockLine[StockCode[not(normalize-space())]]"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($descriptions[$pos])"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to create new `Comment` elements instead of populating the empty `StockCode` then use an approach like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OrderDetails">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="descriptions" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(StockLine[1]/OrderDescription, '\n')"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:with-param name="descriptions" as="xs:string*" select="$descriptions"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="StockLine[StockCode[not(normalize-space())]]">
        <xsl:param name="descriptions"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer">
            <xsl:number count="StockLine[StockCode[not(normalize-space())]]"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            <Comment><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($descriptions[$pos])"/></Comment>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Applying Given XSLT:  <OrderDescription> should split across <Comment> Instead of <StockCode> here is attached output after XSLT http://xsltransform.net/pPzifqt

Comment: My Question is Extension of   this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156641/xslt-string-wraphow-do-i-wrap-words-in-a-string-at-new-line-character-n?lq=1

Comment: Everything looks good only StockCode vales should fall into Comment  elements and StockCode should remain as Empty  value.

Comment: Well, in your question you have described the output you want and it shows `<StockCode>EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS</StockCode>`, it does not show any new `Comment` elements.

Comment: Sorry for Inconvienence . It was great mistake by me. Going to correct it.

Comment: Which is showing <StockCode> WITH VALUE also having comment . instead we want empty <StockCode> only have <comment> value otherwise not. But when  i  applied XSTL :   it is giving me  <StockCode>ABB-CDE-FGH-01</StockCode>
            <Comment>EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS</Comment>

Comment: only Valid if  <StockCode> is empty then <Comment> Must have value. Can we have <xsl:if statement ?

Comment: Thanks for giving me solution. I marked this as my answer. Being Novice please can You please comment the XSLT section .It will be reallyhelpful for me .

Answer (score 1):

To transform your example input you only need to do a template match on the StockCode node like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="StockCode[not(node())]">
    <xsl:variable name="i"><xsl:number count="StockCode[not(node())]"  select="../StockCode[not(node())]"  level="any" /></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(tokenize(ancestor::OrderDetails/StockLine[1]/OrderDescription, '\n')[number($i)])"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The template will only apply for StockCodes with no content. Since this is the only template all other nodes will remain the same in the output (due to the identity template).
The matching template will count all previous StockCode nodes that are empty and use this as an index to locate the tokenized text of the description.

Comment: Thanks for giving me solution